# Display componnant inside PRIME-NG GMap infoWindow

Tags: angular, google-maps, primeng

there's any way to display the component directly inside GMap infoWindow dialogue ?

[I want to change this html code (as string) directly by a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feTHt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can get a reference pointing to that component using ViewChild, like

```
@ViewChild(ExampleComponent, { read: ElementRef }) exampleComponent: any;
```

Then you can access its HTML with nativeElement.innerHTML and use it in the infoWindow.setContent function

```
  handleOverlayClick(event: any) {
    this.infoWindow.setContent(this.exampleComponent.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    this.infoWindow.open(event.map, event.overlay);
    event.map.setCenter(event.overlay.getPosition());
  }
```